# jQuery table issue when looping

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create one table but there is two loop since there are two array that are need to be include in the table.

Here is the two array (from console view):

Object { quota: (5) […], productName: (5) […] }

In quota there is numbers related to each of the productName.

Here is the code part for that table.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://ayambrand-com-my-v1.cloudaccess.host/index.php?option=com_echarity&format=raw&task=api.get_product_name",
    data: {dataArrayPost : Data},
    success: function(data){
        var a = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(a);
        var prodName = a.productName; 
        var splitProductName = "";
        var prodQty = a.quota; 
        var splitProductQuota = "";
        var contents = '<table id="tableDonateDisplay" class="table table-hover">';
        contents += "<tr>";
        contents += '<th>' + 'Product' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Quantity Need' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Price Each' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'My Donation' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Amount' + '</th>';
        jQuery.each(prodName, function(index, value) {
            splitProductName = value;
            contents += "<tr>";
            contents += '<td>' + splitProductName;
        });
        jQuery.each(prodQty, function(index, value) {
            splitProductQuota = value;
            contents += '</td><td>' + splitProductQuota + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>';
            contents += "</tr>";
        });
        contents += "</tr></table>";
        jQuery('#contentNeed').append(contents);
    }
});
```

The table has become like this. How can I make that quota beside on the product name?

JSON Data:

[image]

Comment: Inspect the table in the console, it is structured improperly. `tr` is not closed.

Comment: By inserting the <tr> on the first loop (splitProductName) it will make the second loop (splitProductQuota ) for quantity need become on below of product name.
The question is how can i make the quantity need become on the same row as product name because they are related to each other.

Comment: can you please post ur json data.i will solve ur problem.

Comment: Uploaded the JSON data @kalai

Comment: this is json format
var a = {
  productName: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  quota: [1, 5, 10, 20]
};

Comment: can you please post in string format @MohdShafiq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to close the `tr` tag of the `th`, then check the index of both iteration:

```js
var a = {
  productName: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  quota: [1, 5, 10, 20]
};
console.log(a);
var prodName = a.productName;
var splitProductName = "";
var prodQty = a.quota;
var splitProductQuota = "";
var contents = '<table id="tableDonateDisplay" class="table table-hover" border="1">';
contents += "<tr>";
contents += '<th>' + 'Product' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Quantity Need' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Price Each' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'My Donation' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Amount' + '</th>';
contents += "</tr>";

jQuery.each(prodName, function(index1, value1) {
  splitProductName = value1;
  contents += "<tr>";
  contents += '<td>' + splitProductName;
  jQuery.each(prodQty, function(index, value) {
    if (index1 == index) {
      splitProductQuota = value;
      contents += '</td><td>' + splitProductQuota + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>';
      contents += "</tr>";
    }

  });
});

contents += "</tr></table>";
jQuery('#contentNeed').append(contents);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentNeed">

</div>
```

I created a mock JSON object.